# What does git commit --cleanup=whitespace do exactly?

Tags: git, whitespace

What does 'git commit --cleanup=whitespace' do? I'm trying to test it out but I cannot figure out what the expected behaviour is (and its git documentation on it is just one line).
If I add it, and someone pulls my code, will they receive a source code with zero whitespace lines in between?

Comment: Based on `whitespace`, you will have soon the `scissors` cleanup mode. see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22653722/6309)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, its just for your commit message, not for your source code.

The `default` mode is cleaning commentaries (lines that begin with a #) and leading and ending empty lines. `whitespace` mode is keeping the comments.

Comment: Oh. What's the best way to handle whitespace in source code in Git? Just make sure each developer does it manually, or does Git provide some tools that assist?

Comment: You can use a formatter in your build chain to take care of it. You can rely on Git for some things, see Formating and whitespace in Pro Git http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html

Answer (score 4):

There will be another alternative to whitespace with Git 1.9.x/2.0 (Q2 2014): cleanup mode "`scissors`".

It is introduced with [commit 75df1f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75df1f434f8cfdac1c8eeacae259ab375c01385b) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds), and the [new `git commit --cleanup` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/75df1f434f8cfdac1c8eeacae259ab375c01385b/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L176-L197):

```
scissors
```

> Same as `whitespace`, except that everything from (and including) the line

```
# ------------------------ >8 ------------------------
```

> is truncated if the message is to be edited.
> "`#`" can be customized with `core.commentChar`.

So you can still keep comment, and remove everything past a certain pre-defined line.

---

Update July 2015 Git 2.5: this scissor is now more robust.

See [commit fbfa097](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbfa0973faf47e475854a8919097d5db29acf536) (09 Jun 2015) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
Helped-by: [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 07528be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07528be1018b72e463404624b8752ead7eb0eb8d), 24 Jun 2015)</sup>

> "`git commit --cleanup=scissors`" was not careful enough to protect
> against getting fooled by a line that looked like scissors.

---

Update May 2019, for upcoming Git 2.22 (Q2 2019):
The list of conflicted paths shown in the editor while concluding a
conflicted merge was shown above the scissors line when the
clean-up mode is set to "scissors", even though it was commented
out just like the list of updated paths and other information to
help the user explain the merge better.

See [commit 1a2b985](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a2b985fb375e7ce14932bfc59365024af2fb6ab), [commit 1055997](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1055997e2fc707a15baf232df2ac481055c14321), [commit d540b70](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d540b70c85ccd08507348785fd210ef8317a864d), [commit ca04dc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca04dc96d13cbe5aead17a936e3b8695b20abb55), [commit f29cd86](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f29cd8620d85543dbef572f522c71991b3736387), [commit 94ca361](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94ca361bfb87b00fad7c19cbb518656279e4329d), [commit b720e1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b720e1e3c3156a46ad1c4f5bbe13c7aeefb25c29), [commit 5caab8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5caab8de8a8861e977ffa6e66f2a5ebfe5b8e56c), [commit b510f0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b510f0beab2e251175ea3d021129b6029c370aa4) (17 Apr 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
Helped-by: [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
See [commit dc42e9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc42e9a83a9e9206566b6bc9b57f431b98682b29) (17 Apr 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
Helped-by: [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b877cb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b877cb4a7ec2fafd03b6a3a70c26370744a32c1b), 08 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `cherry-pick/revert`: add scissors line on merge conflict

> Fix a bug where the scissors line is placed after the `Conflicts:` section, in the case where a merge conflict occurs and `commit.cleanup = scissors`.

---

"[`git commit -v --cleanup=scissors`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/798ddfc17fbbe58494f2af0f71e0b53264ee82b5/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L354)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--v))</sup> used to add the scissors line twice in the log message buffer, which has been corrected with Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e09f1254c54329773904fe25d7c545a1fb4fa920).

See [commit e90cc07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e90cc075cc43f2bf08a8963ae84d3e4da50ebfc3), [commit 688a0a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/688a0a751e9ee032be9fb70d7d63220bc85acae1) (27 Feb 2024) by [Josh Triplett (`joshtriplett`)](https://github.com/joshtriplett).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 798ddfc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/798ddfc17fbbe58494f2af0f71e0b53264ee82b5), 07 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/688a0a751e9ee032be9fb70d7d63220bc85acae1): avoid redundant scissor line with --cleanup=scissors -v
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Triplett</sup>

> [`git commit --cleanup=scissors -v`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/688a0a751e9ee032be9fb70d7d63220bc85acae1/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L232)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---cleanupltmodegt))</sup> prints two scissors lines: one at the start of the comment lines, and the other right before the diff.
> This is redundant, and pushes the diff further down in the user's editor than it needs to be.
>
> Make `wt_status_add_cut_line()` remember if it has added a cut line before, and avoid adding a redundant one.